# how to solve the recurrence $T(n) = 2T(n/3) + n\log n$

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

How do we solve the recurrence $T(n) = 2T(n/3) + n\log n$?

Also, is it possible to solve this recurrence by the Master method?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: It is possible to solve by [Master theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem).

A more generic method is [Akra Bazzi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method), but you don't need that for this problem.

Comment: can not seem to be able to solve it help help help :(

Comment: It looks to me like it fits Case 3 as shown on the Wikipedia page.  $a=2, b=3, f(n)=n \log(n)=\Omega(n^{\log_3 (2)+\epsilon}),$ if you take $\epsilon = 0.4$, say.  $ 2f(\frac{n}{3})=2\frac{n}{3}\log\frac{n}{3}\leq c f(n)$ for large $n$ if $.667\le c \le 1$

Comment: why are you taking $\epsilon =0.4$ , also the logic of c being greater thn .667 is not clear to me , sorry i am a noob :(

Comment: @Bunny: Ross is right. Case 3 fits. I suggest you carefully read what case 3 assumes and at the same time read Ross' comment and try to see how it fits.

Answer (score 3):

In order to apply the Master Theorem we define $a=2$, $b=3$ and
$f\left(n\right)=n\lg n$

Since 
[$n^{log_{3}2+0.4}\approx n$], we have that $f\left(n\right)=\Omega\left(n^{log_{b}a+\epsilon}\right)$,
where $\epsilon=0.4$ . The regularity condition on $f\left(n\right)$
will be verified if, for some $c<1$:
$$2\frac{n}{3}\lg\left(n/3\right)\leq cn\lg(n)$$
 Since it is clear that
$\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)n\left(\lg n-\lg3\right)<\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)n\lg(n)$
 the constant $c=\frac{2}{3}<1$ is such that the regularity condition
is met for sufficiently large n. Thus, case 3 of the Master Theorem
applies and $T\left(n\right)=\Theta\left(n\lg n\right)$, answering
the question.

Comment: The last step seems strange. How did you get rid of the log on the left side, but not the right? Also, can't you just take $c=2/3$ when you have $2\log(n/3)/3 \leq c \log n$?

Answer (score 1):

There  is another  closely  related recurrence  that  admits an  exact
solution. Suppose we have $T(0)=0$ and $T(1)=T(2)=1$ and for $n\ge 3$
$$T(n) = 2 T(\lfloor n/3 \rfloor) + n \lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor.$$

Furthermore let the base three representation of $n$ be
$$n = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor} d_k 3^k.$$

Then  we can  unroll the  recurrence to  obtain the  following **exact**
formula for $n\ge 3$
$$T(n) = 2^{\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor}
+ \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor -1} 
2^j \times (\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor - j) \times 
\sum_{k=j}^{\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor} d_k 3^{k-j}.$$

Now to get an upper bound consider a string of two digits to obtain
$$T(n) \le 2^{\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor}
+ \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor -1} 
2^j \times (\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor - j) \times 
\sum_{k=j}^{\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor} 2 \times 3^{k-j}.$$
This simplifies to
$$(9 \lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor - 18) \times 
3^{\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor}
+ 17 \times 2^{\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor}
+ \lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor + 2.$$

This bound is actually attained and cannot be improved upon, just like
the lower bound,  which occurs with a one digit  followed by zeroes to
give
$$T(n) \ge 2^{\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor}
+ \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor -1} 
2^j \times (\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor - j) \times 
3^{\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor-j}.$$
This simplifies to
$$ (3 \lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor - 6) \times 3^{\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor}
+ 7 \times 2^{\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor}.$$

Joining the dominant terms of the upper and the lower bound we obtain
the asymptotics
$$\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor \times
3^{\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor}
\in \Theta\left(\log_3 n \times 3^{\log_3 n}\right) 
= \Theta\left(\log n \times n\right).$$

Observe that there is a lower order term
$$2^{\lfloor \log_3 n \rfloor}
\in \Theta\left(3^{\log_3 2 \times \log_3 n}\right) 
= \Theta\left(n^{\log_3 2}\right).$$

This term represents the  asymptotics being generated by the recursive
term in the recurrence.

These are both in agreement with what the Master theorem would produce.

This [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/595904/can-master-theorem-be-applied-on-any-of-these) has a series of similar calculations.